# Common If code else code java programming practice

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following code repeated to a lots of places. I would like to know if there is any common practice in Java to define such repetitive code by usage of interface/functional interface/abstract class. The inside logic for if is different but out if else and log is same for all.

```
Optional<ABC> factory = factoryResolver.resolve(XYZ);
if (factory.isPresent()) {
    // Logic varies here
    return X;
} else {
    LOGGER.error("Some logs");
}
return Y;
```

Comment: if the code in the block is different, I see no reason to generalize this.

Comment: Probably a bigger refactoring might be of more use. Now it's just abusing `Optional` for null-check.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the `if`, you can write it as `factory.map(...).orElse(..)`

Comment: @hovanessyan `orElse()` has to return something.

Comment: @hovanessyan it's common for methods to behave as they're documented. So yes, your `orElse(LOGGER.error("asd"));` wouldn't compile.

Comment: @Kayaman you're right! I've misread the docs

Comment: does X and Y have any superclass/superinterface may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is essentially no different from using `null` checks, but in a way that is more opaque and verbose.

A more object-oriented solution would be to take advantage of polymorphism. Rather than returning an `Optional<ABC>`, return an `ABC` directly. If no `ABC` can be resolved for `XYZ`, you can return an `UnresolvedABC` class which implements the `ABC` interface in a way that makes sense (e.g. throws exceptions or logs errors).

For more details, see the [Null Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) (Wikipedia)

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate if using Optional.orElseGet

```
 Optional<ABC> factory = factoryResolver.resolve(XYZ);
 return factory.map((abc) -> X).orElseGet(() -> {
     LOGGER.error("Some logs");
     return Y;
 });
```

Comment: as it stands this is not correct. X is not the content of factory. but with a map in between, it should work.

Comment: No need for the local variable. Just `return factoryResolver.resolve(XYZ).map(...`

Answer (score 0):

You should not create `local variable` here, it's of no use.

```
 factoryResolver.resolve(XYZ)
                .map(x -> X) //Your logic
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    LOGGER.error("Some logs");
                    return Y.
                });
```